# When string subscript is out of range, no exception is thrown

Tags: c++, string

This code doesn't print anything but doesn't produce an error either. Why?

```
string s = "test";
cout << s[5];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `operator[]` for `std::string` is [documented to not do any bounds checking](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.

To read from the string with bounds checking, use [at()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at):

> Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. Bounds checking is performed, exception of type std::out_of_range will be thrown on invalid access.

Comment: Might want to point out this is probably referencing the null byte at the end of the string.

Comment: @Qix: No, I don't want to do that. (1) There is no nul byte at the end of a C++ `std::string`. (2) Even if there were, `s[5]` wouldn't reference that index in the given example.

Comment: Oh duh. You're right. (1) Stupidity, (2) I'm bad at counting :c

Comment: Well, technically there _might_ be a null byte at the end of a `std::string` or anywhere else. It's just hard to get it there, because the implicit conversion from `const char*` removes it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard specifies that what you are doing is undefined behaviour. As per `C++11 21.4.5 basic_string element access`:

> **`const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;`**
>   **`reference operator[](size_type pos);`**
>
> Requires: `pos <= size()`
>
> Returns: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior.
>
> Throws: Nothing.
>
> Complexity: constant time.

In your case, `pos` is *not* less than `size()` so you may think the "otherwise" clause of the "returns" section would normally be applicable, and you'd therefore just get an instance of `charT` which you're not allowed to modify.

**However,** since you're actually violating the "requires" clause, with your `pos` being *greater* than `size()`, all bets are off. The controlling part of the standard is the library-wide:

> `17.6.4.11 Requires paragraph [res.on.required]`
>
> Violation of the preconditions specified in a function’s 'Requires:' paragraph results in undefined behavior unless the function’s 'Throws:' paragraph specifies throwing an exception when the precondition is violated.

---

If you *need* bounds checking, use `at()` instead of `operator[]`:

> **`const_reference at(size_type pos) const;`**
>   **`reference at(size_type pos);`**
>
> Requires: `pos < size()`
>
> Throws: `out_of_range` if `pos >= size()`
>
> Returns: `operator[](pos)`